# How do i disable the horizontal scroll bar in Electron BrowserWindow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How do i disable the horizontal scroll bar in a fixed width and height browser window in Electron?

Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

Try to add this in your CSS

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: One side note to be aware of (mainly for the Question OP, really) is that [`-webkit-scrollbar` is non-standard, meaning that it won't work in all web browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar). But it is the recommended way to do this in Electron.

Comment: This takes away the scrollbar but doesn't disable scrolling capability with the mouse wheel

Comment: this will hide horizontal and vertical scrollbar but will still allow scrolling. the other answer with overlow-x: hidden is better.

Answer (score 15):

I think you just have to disable horizontal scrolling in your HTML file.
One way to do so is by using css:

```
<style>
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

Try to add this in the <head>.

Comment: Good one, but it disables scrolling. Is there a way to hide the bar but maintain scrolling?

Comment: `<style>
      ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
      }
  </style>`  This will work with vertical scrolling, dont know about horizontal (you eventually have to press mouse 2/the scrolling wheel and drag it to the left/right)

Comment: 2018 work for me! I am building a Electron v2.0.0 app for both macOS and Windows, and now I am spending time to fix problem that only exist on Windows, scrolling bar is one of them.