# Nodejs, Electron, how to add a scrollbar?

Tags: node.js, electron

I was wondering how I could add a scrollbar to my electron application for both Windows and Mac horizontally and vertically as some of my users are having an issue seeing the full application as they have small screens.

Comment: Scrollbars should be automatically added if the window is too small to fit all the content. How small are their screens? You could also consider adding a `minWidth`/`minHeight` to the BrowserWindow options and just making sure your content fits nicely in that space

Comment: @pushkin it's the HTML that gets cut off so I was wondering if I could add a scrollbar, they don't seem to get added automatically?

Comment: Does this affect the page in your first renderer process or in your webview? Is it feasible to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @pushkin No because I don't have the problem myself, I just want a scrollbar it can be based anywhere.

Comment: You can't reproduce the problem?

Comment: No @pushkin I just need a scrollbar though

Comment: like I said, in my experience scrollbars should automatically appear. I'm confused why you can't reproduce this. Even if you shrink your window down, your content will still fit nicely in the window? Have your users posted an image of the problem somewhere?

Comment: @pushkin For some reason if there screen isn't big enough stuff just goes away, are there any options you need to state to have a scrollbar when creating the browser window? And is there any possibility I've accidently disabled it?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990519/how-do-i-disable-the-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-electron-browserwindow). Make sure you aren't doing that. Regarding "any options you need to state...", I don't believe so. You can try downloading the electron quickstart app and making sure that you see the scrollbars there when the window is too small

Comment: @pushkin That's weird I am using the electrion starter app

Comment: @pushkin Anything you can see here that would stop the scrollbar? https://www.pastebin.com/VC1ALczH

Comment: Have you made any relevant changes to it? I can see scrollbars when I run it

Comment: Is what you posted exactly what's in the quick start app?

Comment: @pushkin I posted a pastebin of my main.js above

Comment: Works for me. If you shrink it down to a tiny window, you'll see scrollbars

Comment: @pushkin Neither me or my users get a scrollbar?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNja8.png) is what I see. I presume your users aren't running the quickstart app, but your app. It would help to post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @pushkin I posted a pastebin of my code above

Comment: Oh, that's your full app? I could get the scrollbars there too... (though I only tested on Windows)

Comment: @pushkin I don't understand why the scroll bar isn't working then? Can html break it?

Comment: Actually, you only pasted your JS. Did you modify your HTML/CSS at all, or is it exactly the same as what's in the electron quickstart app?

Comment: @pushkin I modified it a lot, would that effect the scrollbar tho?

Comment: Yes, it very well could. Again, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990519/how-do-i-disable-the-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-electron-browserwindow) for an example of this.

Answer (score 3):

For the [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) I went to the global css file `app.global.css` and changed the body style from `overflow-y: hidden;` to `overflow-y: scroll;` and it worked like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

You may need to discover what is removing the scrollbar from your Electron application, and then adapt from there. For example, I use [App.js](http://code.kik.com/app/3/docs.html) in my Electron application. By inspecting on the elements in the developer tools, I discovered [App.js](http://code.kik.com/app/3/docs.html) gives the body of the html a class name `.app-no-scrollbar`, and this gives the view a style with no scrollbar. The easy solution is to add `$('body').removeClass('app-no-scrollbar')` at the bottom of the javascript file (yes, I'm using jQuery), and this allows the scrollbar to show as normal.